how to call "/server server_name" from bukkit plugin
I used Velocity proxy
I need call
/server server_name
from my Bukkit plugin
I tried to call a command with
player.chat("/server server_name")
but I got the error " undefined command "
Minecraft version 1.16.5
also, i tried  these
    player.chat("/server " + targetWorld);
    Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "server " + targetWorld);
    player.performCommand("server " + targetWorld);

not work at all

You can not call a Proxy command from a subserver. What you want to do is use PluginMessaging.
  ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
  out.writeUTF("Connect");
  out.writeUTF("server_name"); // Replace with your actual server name as specified in velocity.toml or config.yml
  player.sendPluginMessage(this, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());

